# Creating a 2 dimensional character array dynamically in C++

Tags: visual-c++

I want to create a 2 dimensional character array dynamically through pointers. Then input 10 strings in it and then take a string target from user and find it in array. if it is present then return its index. I have written code for it but it has errors. Please help me in correcting it. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int strsearch(char [][50],char *);
int main()
{
    char str[10][50];
    char *target=new char [50];
    int index;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        str = new char* [50];
        str++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter a sting";
        cin>>str[i][50];
        str++;
    }
    cout<<"Enter a string to find:";
    cin>>target;
    index=strsearch(str,target);
    if(index<0)
    {
        cout<<"String not found";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"String exist at location "<<index<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int strsearch(char string[10][50],char *fstr)
{
    int slen;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        slen=strlen(**string);
        if (strnicmp(*string[50],fstr,slen)== 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
std::vector<std::string> obj;
```

It will save you all the head & heart aches and guard you against easy to go wrong manual memory management issues. What you are trying to do is to solve the problem C way. With C++ the correct way to do it is using a vector of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an error in any case:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    slen=strlen(**string);
    if (strnicmp(*string[50],fstr,slen)== 0)
    {
       return i;
    }
 }
```

Must be something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    slen=strlen(string[i]);
    if (strnicmp(string[i],fstr,slen)== 0)
    {
       return i;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some correction, i think it can help you but i have not compiled to check for errors.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#define DIM_1 10 // Avoid to use "magic numbers" in your code
#define DIM_2 50

using namespace std;
int strsearch(char **string,char *fstr);
int main()
{
    char **str = new char*[DIM_1]; //char str[10][50]; dynamically allocated array.
    char *target=new char [DIM_2];
    int index;
    for(int i=0; i<DIM_1; i++)
    {
        str[i] = new char[DIM_2]; //Do not lost the original pointer
        //str++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<DIM_1; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter a sting";
        cin>>str[i][DIM_2];
        //str++; Do not lost the original pointer
    }
    cout<<"Enter a string to find:";
    cin>>target;
    index=strsearch(str,target);
    if(index<0)
    {
        cout<<"String not found";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"String exist at location "<<index<<endl;
    }
    // Free memory!!
    for (int i=0; i<DIM_1;i++) delete[] str[i];
    delete[] str;
    delete[] target;

    return 0;
}

int strsearch(char **string,char *fstr) //its dinamicly allocated array
{
    int slen;
    int result=-1; //Only one return-> structured programming
    for(int i=0;i<DIM_1;i++)
    {
        slen=strlen(**string);
        //strlen and strnicmp is C, not C++, check string class.
        if (strnicmp(string[i],fstr,DIM_2)== 0) //Find in the string[i]
        {
            result= i;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your code has few errors. But I removed them. It also corrects my some errors. Thanks.